# SUM() in GROUP_CONCAT() and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I am trying to `SUM()` columns in my stock table by using `GROUP_CONCAT()` but cannot seem to get the output that I am looking for.

MySQL tables :

```
CREATE TABLE 'suppliers' (
 'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 'supplier_code' varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 'name' varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 'vat_registration_number' varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 'contact_name' varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
 'email_address' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 'phone_number' varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
 'address' varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
 'suburb' varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
 'city' varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
 'zip' varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 'deleted' enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE 'warehouses' (
 'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 'name' varchar(65) NOT NULL,
 'disabled' enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 'deleted' enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE 'stock_items' (
 'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 'supplier_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
 'stock_code' varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 'description' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 'type' enum('product','service') NOT NULL,
 'selling_price' decimal(19,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 'inclusive_vat' enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
 'barcode' varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 'deleted' enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE 'stock' (
 'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 'stock_item_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
 'warehouse_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
 'supplier_invoice_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
 'quantity' int(11) NOT NULL,
 'cost_price' decimal(19,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 'deleted' enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

My current query:

```
SELECT 
    stock.id,
    stock_items.stock_code,
    GROUP_CONCAT(warehouses.name ORDER BY warehouses.id) as warehouse,
    GROUP_CONCAT(stock.quantity ORDER BY warehouses.id) as stock_in_warehouse
FROM stock 
LEFT JOIN stock_items ON stock_items.id = stock.stock_item_id
LEFT JOIN warehouses ON warehouses.id = stock.warehouse_id
WHERE stock_items.deleted='0' 
GROUP BY stock.stock_item_id
```

gives me the output of

`id | stock_code | warehouse   | stock_in_warehouse`

`1  | MIKHAPLITE | One,One,Two | 4,5,2`

I need the `GROUP_CONCAT() as warehouse` to `GROUP BY(warehouses.id)` and `GROUP_CONCAT() as stock_in_warehouse` to `SUM(stock.quantity)` so that the output looks like:

`id | stock_code | warehouse | stock_in_warehouse`

`1  | MIKHAPLITE | One,Two   | 9,2`

I have tried using CAST() as mentioned in other posts/forums and other methods mentioned [here](https://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/group_concat.php) but cannot seem to get what I am trying to do.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the supporting sample data

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3444e49e37c5444ae1571325a547d937).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I have found the query that I was looking for:

```
SELECT
    der.stock_code,
    der.description,
    der.type,
    der.selling_price,
    der.inclusive_vat,
    der.barcode,
    GROUP_CONCAT(der.warehouse) warehouse,
    GROUP_CONCAT(der.stock_in_warehouse) stock_in_warehouse
FROM (
    SELECT
        der.stock_code,
        der.description,
        der.type,
        der.selling_price,
        der.inclusive_vat,
        der.barcode,
        der.warehouse,
        SUM(der.stock_in_warehouse) stock_in_warehouse
    FROM (
        SELECT  
            stock_items.stock_code, 
            stock_items.description,
            stock_items.type,
            stock_items.selling_price,
            stock_items.inclusive_vat,
            stock_items.barcode,
            stock.quantity as stock_in_warehouse, 
            warehouses.name as warehouse 
        FROM stock
            LEFT JOIN stock_items ON stock_items.id = stock.stock_item_id
            LEFT JOIN warehouses ON warehouses.id = stock.warehouse_id
            WHERE stock_items.deleted='0' 
            ORDER BY 
                stock.id,
                warehouses.id
    ) der
    GROUP BY
        der.stock_code,
        der.warehouse
    ORDER BY 
        der.warehouse
) der
GROUP BY
    der.stock_code
ORDER BY
    der.warehouse
```